# mvc app on production server - ninject, routing, areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, ninject, asp.net-mvc-areas

The problem is with my app in production environment. When I publish my MVC app on production server ninject stops working, and page page loads about 30s, same time takes controller method to just throw back true/false(ajax query). Unfortunately, only information that administrator of hosting company gave me was:[log from IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDYZ5.png)

My application has:

1. MVC project(4) - EntityFramework + Ninject,

   Important thing is that my LandingPage which I would like to show at the 
   beginning is in Area called "LandingPage" with controller named "Landing"
2. Repository project
3. DB project with interfaces to models

My RouteConfig is:

```
    var route = routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Landing", action = "Index", id = 
    UrlParameter.Optional }
    ).DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "LandingPage"}
    );
```

I thought that problem sits in Ninject configuration, but after today's info from hosting company I don't have any clue what to do with this problem.

Edit:
My RegisterService:

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IEmailRepository>().To<EmailRepository>();

    }
```

My Controller:

```
    private readonly IEmailRepository repository;
    public LandingController(IEmailRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
```

EmailRepository:

```
public class EmailRepository : IEmailRepository
{
    ReliableDB context;

    public EmailRepository(ReliableDB context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void InsertOrUpdate(string emailAddress)
    {
        LPEmail item = new LPEmail();
        item.Date = DateTime.Now.Date;
        item.Email_Address = emailAddress;
        context.LPEmail.Add(item);
    }

    public bool EmailExists(string emailAddress)
    {
        bool result = context.LPEmail.Any(w => w.Email_Address == emailAddress);
        return result;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show how you register services inside Ninject IoC container?

Comment: @Win could you take a look please

Comment: What does EmailRepository do? Sending email using SMTP?

Comment: No, email repository checks whether mail is in database, if not it saves it, and then I send mail with SMTP. When I comment repository then sending email works....but still takes about 30s to get back  from controller to view. Even more, when I comment sending mail and return only 'true' to view it takes 30s as well.

Comment: Could you show us EmailRepository?  The issue could be inside that class.

Comment: I do not see anything inside EmailRepository that slow you down, unless database responses is slow. Could you run a performance profile, and see which method takes more time? For example, [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), [DotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)

Comment: Normally, sending email takes time. Does the application wait for the response back from email server?

Comment: When SendEmail method returns only 'true' its also takes about 30s to return value from controller. Maybe I have made mistake with injecting ReliableDB to EmailRepository constructor...?? ReliableDB inherits from dbContext